# Clip path positioning right edge with absolute values and custom shape (CSS/SVG)

Tags: html, css, svg, mask, clip-path

I am facing a problem and hope for help.

In picture 1 you can see the design of my client. This is about the custom shape. The shape must have exactly this curve and the 45 degree angle.
[Picture 1 design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JYtU.jpg)

In picture 2 you can see my html/css prototype so far.
[Picture 2 prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTcMt.jpg)

I simply drew the Custom Shape very large in Adobe Illustrator and extracted it as a SVG Path:

```
<clipPath id="clipListing">
<path d="m2776.45,1174.67L2784.45,0H100.2C11.11,0-33.51,107.71,29.49,170.71l1004.12,1004.12,1742.83-.17Z"/>
</clipPath>
```

I assigned the path to my box using the clip-path property in CSS. This allows the box to grow in height (with more text) without changing the angle of the custom shape.

Problem: I now want to flip/reverse/invert the shape for the 2nd element. But since the shape always starts from the upper left edge, this does not work.

With objectBoundingBox I don't get further, because then the rounding and the angle changes. Also tricks like dir="rtl" or scaleX(-1) did not help.

Does anyone have a solution or approach for me, how to make the path start from the top right? Thanks :)

**Edit:** It does work with scaleX(-1). Sorry!

Working code example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #ele {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100vh;
                clip-path: url(#clip);
                background: red;
                transform: scaleX(-1);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ele"></div>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
            <clipPath id="clip">
                <path d="m2776.45,1174.67L2784.45,0H100.2C11.11,0-33.51,107.71,29.49,170.71l1004.12,1004.12,1742.83-.17Z"/>
            </clipPath>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you put just enough code into your question to create a runnable snippet - it makes it much easier to help. In particular it would be good to see what the scale does/doesn't do. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am very sorry. I have built a test after your comment (added in original comment). And here it worked with scaleX(-1). I then tested this again in my project and now it worked. The error was elsewhere by me.